# Booting from a partition (not a seperate hard drive) in virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I want to boot my Ubuntu partition in virtualbox, but I can't figure out how to have the virtual hard disk file target the correct partition on Windows. Since I'm on a laptop, both of my operating systems are on the same hard drive, so just targeting the drive would probably end in disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you already have a virtualbox file contain Ubuntu partition in an external hard drive and you want to boot it in your laptop? It should be fine. You just need to locate the path correctly. take a kook at this https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33899

Comment: What I mean is that I have a physical partition on my laptop's hard drive, alongside Windows, and I want to boot it, but the link helped me nonetheless. Unfortunately, after targeting the partition, the VM says that no bootable media is found. I think I may make a new question for this issue.